# Can I replace my laptop screen with another one with a lower resolution?

Tags: laptop, resolution

My Acer Aspire laptop (Acer Aspire V3-771G-53218G75Maii) has a broken screen and I would like to replace it. 
It seems that this model came in two resolutions (1920×1080 and 1600×900). Can I put a 1600×900 screen on my laptop although it original came with 1920×1080? 
(I know that vice versa can be a problem because of the processor and I am guessing that this way should work, but I would anyway like to be sure).

Comment: There are dozens of Aspire models. Which one?

Comment: @FleetCommand Acer Aspire V3-771G-53218G75Maii

Comment: There should be no problem putting a lower resolution screen to replace a higher resolution one. The answer is YES you can.

Comment: I take it, you want the lower res because of cost?  Seems unnecessary.  You have to do the research the get the raw screen PN, but once you have that, it will be plug / play for under $75.  About 5 years ago, I paid about $100 for a 17" 1920  x 1080 dell.  Only thing that was off, was the PN was one number off and never could adjust the screen brightness, which stayed at 100%.